# How to use a function as a parameter to a stored procedure in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I created a function in Postgres that returns a table with a varying number of rows.

`NewProducts()` is another function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RetrieveRebates(customerID INT)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        customer INT,  
        reb NUMERIC,
        prod INT
    )
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT rebate_default.customer_id AS customer, rebate_default.rebate_group AS reb, NewProducts.product_id AS prod FROM NewProducts(customerID)
JOIN rebate_default ON NewProducts.group = rebate_default.group
WHERE rebate_default.customer_id=customerID;
$$;
```

I want to insert all the rows from this table into another table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertData(SELECT * FROM RetrieveRebates(customerID))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (customer);
    INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (prod);
    INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (reb);
END;
```

How can I use a table as a parameter of a stored procedure and add all rows from this table parameter to another table?

Comment: Do you really want to insert three rows with only one of the columns having data?

Comment: Why not just pass the customer id and then call the function inside the procedure? `insert into table3 (...) select customer, prod, reb from RetrieveRebates(customerID);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name didn't think about it! Your suggestion works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do...